# Function not approving the NFT through interface

Tags: solidity, nft, openzeppelin, auctions

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract Test {
    function transferToken(address _contract,address to ,uint256 _tokenId) public{
        // IERC721 token = IERC721(_contract);
        IERC721(_contract).transferFrom(msg.sender, to, _tokenId);
    }
    function transferToContract(address _contract,uint256 _tokenId) public{
        IERC721 token = IERC721(_contract);
        token.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender,address(this), _tokenId, "");
    }
    function approveNFT(address _contract, address operator, bool approved) public{
        IERC721 token = IERC721(_contract);
        // token.setApprovalForAll(msg.sender, approved);
        token.setApprovalForAll(operator, approved);
    }
    function checkName(address _contract) public view returns (string memory){
        ERC721 token = ERC721(_contract);
        return token.name();
    }
    function checkSender() public view returns (address,address){
        return (msg.sender,address(this));
    }
    function isItApprovedForAll(address _contract,address owner) public view returns (bool){
        IERC721 token = IERC721(_contract);
        return token.isApprovedForAll(owner,_contract);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make auction contract for nft. For this purpose first I need to give permission for auction contract to tranfer user's nft . I tried giving permission to auction contract using IERC721 Openzepplin standard but it is not working as expected.

Current Behavior : when function approvenft() gets  executed the fuction isitapprovedforall() shows true but while transfering nft it shows  "ERC721: caller is not token owner nor approved" and also the IERC getapproved() function is not showing shows the newly approved address

Expected Behavior : after approving the nft using approvenft() it should be transferable.

Comment: A contract C cannot approve itself to access user U tokens. It is U who has to call approve on C address. Another option is for the token contract to have that functionality.

Comment: Remember one thing, whenever you call any function through interface the msg.sender for that function is the contract which is calling that function , not the wallet form which you are calling it.